Filter Component is not updating Input in Angular
I have an Angular component where I am using a Filter component.
The filter component takes  [buttonText] to have a button label.
Initially the buttonText is shown but I do want to update the label with the current selected checkboxes of the filter.
The filter button does not show the new baseText, which gets updated in the onFilterCheckboxChange function and I do not know how to update this or to have the component to re-render.
{{baseText}} renders every change the new information but [buttonText]="baseText" gets not updated.
<div class="drv-grid">
  <div drv-row="" class="drv-row">
    <div drv-col=""
      class="drv-bg--ui-05 drv-pt-md--02 drv-pb-md--02 drv-pt-sm--01 drv-pb-sm--01 drv-col-md-12 drv-col-sm-4">

      {{baseText}}

      <drv-filter #filterComponent class="drv-filter" [labelVisible]="labelVisible" [id]="id" [multiple]="true"
        [buttonText]="baseText" [showResetButton]="showResetButton" ismultiselect="true" [options]="[]">

        <drv-textinput id="filterSearch" label="Filter durchsuchen" type="search" (input)="onInput()"></drv-textinput>

        <div *ngIf="filteredOptions.length > 0" class="filter-search__filterSuggestion">
          <label *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" class="filter-search__filterCheckbox"
            (change)="onFilterCheckboxChange(option.value)">
            <drv-checkbox [id]="'checkbox_' + option.label" [required]="false">
              {{ option.label }}
            </drv-checkbox>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="filter-search__AnwendenBtn drv-pt-md--02 drv-pb-md--02 drv-pt-sm--01 drv-pb-sm--01">
          <drv-button id="" label="Anwenden" fullSizeOption="full" />
        </div>

      </drv-filter>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import * as data from '../../assets/data.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'filter-search',
  templateUrl: './filter-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-search.component.scss'],
  host: { 'class': 'filter-search' },
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class FilterSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  labelVisible: boolean = false;
  id!: string;
  showResetButton: boolean = true;
  selected?: boolean;
  baseText: string = '';
  selectCount: number = 0;
  searchValue = "";

  vorgaenge = (data as any).default;
  neueVorgaenge: string[] = [];
  selectedFilteroption: string[] = [];

  getData = this.vorgaenge.map((item: any) => {
    if (item.ausloeser.ausloesende_person.drv_id) {
      this.neueVorgaenge.push(item.ausloeser.ausloesende_person.drv_id);
      return this.neueVorgaenge;
    }
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData;
  }

  options = this.neueVorgaenge.map(item => ({ value: item, label: item }));
  filteredOptions = [...this.options];

  onInput() {
    this.searchValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('filterSearch')).value;

    this.filteredOptions = this.options.filter(item =>
      item.value.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchValue.toLowerCase())
    );
  }

  onFilterCheckboxChange(event: any) {
    const index = this.selectedFilteroption.indexOf(event);

    if (index === -1) {
      this.selectedFilteroption.push(event);
    } else {
      this.selectedFilteroption.splice(index, 1);
    }

    this.selectCount = this.selectedFilteroption.length;
    this.baseText = this.selectCount.toString();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}



I already tried ngOnChanges but this was not called.

Please share the drv-filter Component code?
